# Same objects merge and filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I need to filter objects by their status id. I also need data and csr counts for each item. There are multiple items for each `StatusName`:

```js
[
    {
        "StatusId": 2,
        "StatusName": "ordered",
        "CSR_NameId": 2,
        "CSR_Name": "test"
    },
    {
        "StatusId": 3,
        "StatusName": "delivered",
        "CSR_NameId": 3,
        "CSR_Name": "test2"
    },
    {
        "StatusId": 5,
        "StatusName": "created",
        "CSR_NameId": 2,
        "CSR_Name": "test"
    },
    {
        "StatusId": 27,
        "StatusName": "quoted",
        "CSR_NameId": 2,
        "CSR_Name": "test"
    }
]
```

I need output like this:

```
[
    
  {
     "ordered":{
       "all": 2,
        "test": 1,
         "test2": 1
         },
      "delivered": {
        "all": 3,
        "test": 2,
        "test2": 1
      },
      "created": {
         "all": 2,
         "test": 2
       },
      "quoted": {
        "all": 1,
        "test": 1
      }
  }
]
```

I tried like this and I encountered this output:

```js
// get unique ID
datas.forEach(i => !uniq.includes(i.StatusId) ? uniq.push(i.StatusId) : '' );
    // filter by ID
    uniq.forEach(id => {
    res.push(datas.filter(o => o.StatusId === id));
})
```

```js
[ [ { StatusId: 2, StatusName: 'ordered', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test"}, { StatusId: 2, StatusName: 'ordered', CSR_NameId: 3, "CSR_Name": "test2" } ], [ { StatusId: 3, StatusName: 'delivered', CSR_NameId: 3, "CSR_Name": "test2" }, { StatusId: 3, StatusName: 'delivered', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test" }, { StatusId: 3, StatusName: 'delivered', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test" } ], [ { StatusId: 5, StatusName: 'created', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test" }, { StatusId: 5, StatusName: 'created', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test" } ], [ { StatusId: 27, StatusName: 'quoted', CSR_NameId: 2, "CSR_Name": "test" } ] ]
```

I need to fix this javascript code. I used forEach method and going to result. But I cannot do anything then.

Comment: Please format your question properly. Avoid bold text. Check if the question is asked previously and consult documentation before asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object that contains the counts for each type, updated on each iteration.

```js
let arr=[{StatusId:2,StatusName:"ordered",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"},{StatusId:2,StatusName:"ordered",CSR_NameId:3,CSR_Name:"test2"},{StatusId:3,StatusName:"delivered",CSR_NameId:3,CSR_Name:"test2"},{StatusId:3,StatusName:"delivered",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"},{StatusId:3,StatusName:"delivered",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"},{StatusId:5,StatusName:"created",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"},{StatusId:5,StatusName:"created",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"},{StatusId:27,StatusName:"quoted",CSR_NameId:2,CSR_Name:"test"}];
let res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const o = acc[curr.StatusName] ??= {all: 0};
  o[curr.CSR_Name] = (o[curr.CSR_Name] || 0) + 1;
  ++o.all;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{"StatusId":2,"StatusName":"ordered","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"},{"StatusId":2,"StatusName":"ordered","CSR_NameId":3,"CSR_Name":"test2"},{"StatusId":3,"StatusName":"delivered","CSR_NameId":3,"CSR_Name":"test2"},{"StatusId":3,"StatusName":"delivered","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"},{"StatusId":3,"StatusName":"delivered","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"},{"StatusId":5,"StatusName":"created","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"},{"StatusId":5,"StatusName":"created","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"},{"StatusId":27,"StatusName":"quoted","CSR_NameId":2,"CSR_Name":"test"}]

console.log(arr.reduce((a, {StatusName:n, CSR_Name:c}, t) =>
  ((t=a[n]??={all:0})[c]??=0, t.all++, t[c]++, a), {}))
```